# how can i found my uploaded application from android market

Tags: android

i have uploaded an application in android market that was displayed in my android device. i have recently upload next version for that application but that application not displayed in my device android market. i have tested my apk file in my device working good but in device android market doesn't display my latest version application. can any one help me.
i have used the following code in manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true">
    </supports-screens>
thanks in advance.
```

Comment: What about renaming your version code and version name?

Comment: version code="2" version name="1.1.0" this is my latest version

Comment: Have you signed your next version with the same key that you had used to sign your previous version?

Comment: yes i have used same keystores

Comment: Ok! In that case, see my comment @Tony's answer.

Comment: Can you post your entire manifest file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your previous comment please change your api version compatible to your device.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /> this is for 2.1 similarly whats ur moblie android version and ur app version?

Comment: i use <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> and my mobile is version is 2.3.3

Comment: @Donald then he is fine, as it is minimum SDK

Comment: @tony i have one problem can you help me

Comment: @tony plz check this link i need ur help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108642/androidplay-audio-files-using-single-mediaplayer-object-and-also-display-images

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the web market? That should show if the app is compatiable with your registered device...

Comment: ya i have seen one message as "not compatiable with this device" but i have tested my application with this device before i uploaded in android market. can u please tell me how can i fix this.

Comment: @user1084935: One of the reasons could be that your `minSdkVersion` is greater than the Android version running on the mobile.

Comment: Does it tell you why it is not supported? Screen size? Location? etc