# ERROR : threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb60734f0)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an bustin bieber app and when i run it it says :

```
threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb60734f0)
```

I don't know wath i do wrong!
This is my code:

```
//Packege
    package com.stony.bustinbieber;

   //Imports
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    //counter

    int counter = 0;

    ImageButton finishhimbutton;
    ImageButton resetbutton;
    ImageView jb1;
    ImageView jb2;
    ImageView jb3;
    ImageView jb4;
    ImageView jb5;
    ImageView jb6;
        MediaPlayer mp1;
        MediaPlayer mp2;
        MediaPlayer mp3;
        TextView txtCount;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.slap);
            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.resetsound);
            mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.drawable.fatality);
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
            jb1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB1);
            jb2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB2);
            jb3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB3);
            jb4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB4);
            jb5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB5);
            jb6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.JB6);
            finishhimbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.finishhim);
            resetbutton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reserbutton);


        txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);              


            finishhimbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        //Finish him button

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    counter++;
                    txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                    mp1.start();
               switch(counter){


                    case 10:
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                        break;

                    case 20:
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                        break;

                    case 30:
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                        break;

                    case 40:
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

                        break;
                    case 50:            
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        mp3.start();

                         break;

                    case 51:
                        jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                        jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                        counter = 0;
                        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));

                        break;

                     default:

                         break;



                    }

                    }
                }



    );



    resetbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     //Reset Button   

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               

                mp2.start();
                counter = 0;
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
                jb1.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
                jb2.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb3.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb4.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb5.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
                jb6.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);

            }

        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`txtCount` is not initialized

```
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Also there is no need to create 3 MediaPlayer objects. You can have one and play different songs.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

[android:play audio files using single mediaplayer object and also display images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108642/androidplay-audio-files-using-single-mediaplayer-object-and-also-display-images)

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

will come after

```
txtCount = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);
```

because if you try to use it before that it will be null